# why this circular import *will* work in python

Tags: python, python-import

I have found a strange circular reference in my code and here is the minimum code:

```
ph
|-- mod
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- pkg.py  # import mod.sub_mod.sub_pkg
|   `-- sub_mod
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- sub_pkg.py  # from mod import pkg
`-- main.py
```

in `mod`, only `pkg.py` and `sub_pkg.py` have file content.

In `main.py`:

```
import mod.pkg
```

will cause an `ImportError`, but

```
import mod.sub_mod.sub_pkg
```

works well.

when i am trying to find this minimal reproducible example, i found that in python 3, both import will work.
I also found this page: https://gist.github.com/datagrok/40bf84d5870c41a77dc6 but i still don't know why.

Comment: Maybe see [“Importing Python Modules” on effbot.org](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start the circular import with `import mod.pkg`, then `mod/pkg.py` starts first, and tries to `import mod.sub_mod.sub_pkg`. `mod/sub_mod/sub_pkg.py` starts, and tries to run `from mod import pkg`, but the `mod.pkg` module is already being initialized.

Python skips to trying to retrieve the `pkg` attribute from the `mod` module object. However, that attribute isn't set until the `mod.pkg` module finishes initializing, so `from mod import pkg` fails.

---

If you start the circular import with `import mod.sub_mod.sub_pkg`, then `mod/sub_mod/sub_pkg.py` starts first, and tries to run `from mod import pkg`. `mod/pkg.py` starts, and tries to `import mod.sub_mod.sub_pkg`. The `mod.sub_mod.sub_pkg` module is already initialized, but Python doesn't try to access attributes this time.

`from mod import pkg` needs to retrieve the `pkg` attribute from `mod` because it needs to bind the value of that attribute to the name `pkg` in the local namespace. However, `import mod.sub_mod.sub_pkg` only binds the `mod` name in the local namespace. Python binds the `mod` name to the `mod` module in `mod.pkg`'s module namespace and continues on.

---

In Python 3, in the first case, there's a fallback when `from mod import pkg` fails to find the `pkg` attribute on `mod`. Python checks the `sys.modules` dict for an entry for `'mod.pkg'`, finds one, and binds the module it finds to the `pkg` name.